# How can I add words chapter and appendix in TOC with document class book?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, titletoc

I am using TU delft thesis template : http://www.tudelft.nl/thema/handleiding-huisstijl/downloads/ 
 Only chapter numbers and appendix appear in toc, but I want the words chapter and appendix along with them. But I do not want them in the titles itself. In the title, I just want numbers for `\mainmatter` and letters for `\appendix`
[image: This is how it is as of now]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a MWE to help us help you.

Comment: A screen shot does not really reveal which code you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use the class `dissertation.cls` from [in this zip archive](http://www.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/Files/tudelft/themasites/Huisstijl/dissertation-tudelft-latex-ff9d073.zip) on the web page that you link to, which loads the class `book` and (among others) the package `titletoc`. Then you can achieve what you want by adding the following lines to your preamble:

```
%%% The following lines add Chapter or Appendix in front of the number
\titlecontents{chapter}%
  [0pt]%
  {\vspace{1ex}}%
  {\bfseries\chapappname\ \thecontentslabel\quad}%
  {\bfseries}%
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}
%%% Initially, for the main part of the document, set the label to "Chapter"
\let\chapappname\chaptername
```

Moreover, after the `\appendix` command, add the line

```
%%% Sets the label in the table of contents to "Appendix"
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\chapappname\string\appendixname}
```

There is a problem, though: Due to a LaTeX bug you may not use `\include` to include the code for the appendix. Instead, use `\input` or write it directly into the main file.

```
%%% The appendices have to be included with `\input`, not `\include`
%%% due to a bug in LaTeX, otherwise the appendices will also be
%%% labeled "Chapter"
\input{appendix-a/appendix-a}
%%% Wrong: \include{appendix-a/appendix-a}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{dissertation}
%%% The following lines add Chapter or Appendix in front of the number
\titlecontents{chapter}%
  [0pt]%
  {\vspace{1ex}}%
  {\bfseries\chapappname\ \thecontentslabel\quad}%
  {\bfseries}%
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}
%%% Initially, for the main part of the document, set the label to "Chapter"
\let\chapappname\chaptername
\begin{document}

%% Specify the title and author of the thesis. This information will be used on
%% the title page (in title/title.tex) and in the metadata of the final PDF.
\title[Optional Subtitle]{Title}
\author{Albert}{Einstein}

%% Use Roman numerals for the page numbers of the title pages and table of
%% contents.
\frontmatter

\include{title/title}

%% The (optional) dedication can be used to thank someone or display a
%% significant quotation.
\dedication{\epigraph{Science is a wonderful thing \\ if one does not have to earn one's living at it.}{Albert Einstein}}

\tableofcontents

\include{summary/summary}
\include{preface/preface}

%% Use Arabic numerals for the page numbers of the chapters.
\mainmatter

%% Turn on thumb indices.
\thumbtrue

\include{chapter-1/chapter-1}
\include{conclusion/conclusion}
\include{epilogue/epilogue}
\include{acks/acks}

%% Use letters for the chapter numbers of the appendices.
\appendix
%%% Sets the label in the table of contents to "Appendix"
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\chapappname\string\appendixname}

%%% The appendices have to be included with `\input`, not `\include`
%%% due to a bug in LaTeX, otherwise the appendices will also be
%%% labeled "Chapter"
\input{appendix-a/appendix-a}

%% Turn off thumb indices for unnumbered chapters.
\thumbfalse

\include{cv/cv}
\include{publications/publications}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:** To make the toc entries for chapters entirely cyan and the ones for (sub)sections entirely black (as requested in the comments), add the following lines to the preamble (replacing the lines shown above).

```
%%% The following lines add Chapter or Appendix in front of the number
\titlecontents{chapter}%
  [0pt]%
  {\vspace{1ex}}%
  {\color{title}\bfseries\chapappname\ \thecontentslabel\quad}%
  {\bfseries}%
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}
%%% Initially, for the main part of the document, set the label to "Chapter"
\let\chapappname\chaptername
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]%
  {}%
  {\colorlet{title}{black}\contentslabel{2.3em}}%
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}%
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [6.8em]%
  {}%
  {\colorlet{title}{black}\contentslabel{3.0em}}%
  {\hspace*{-3.0em}}%
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{dissertation}
%%% The following lines add Chapter or Appendix in front of the number
\titlecontents{chapter}%
  [0pt]%
  {\vspace{1ex}}%
  {\color{title}\bfseries\chapappname\ \thecontentslabel\quad}%
  {\bfseries}%
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}
%%% Initially, for the main part of the document, set the label to "Chapter"
\let\chapappname\chaptername
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]%
  {}%
  {\colorlet{title}{black}\contentslabel{2.3em}}%
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}%
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [6.8em]%
  {}%
  {\colorlet{title}{black}\contentslabel{3.0em}}%
  {\hspace*{-3.0em}}%
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\begin{document}

%% Specify the title and author of the thesis. This information will be used on
%% the title page (in title/title.tex) and in the metadata of the final PDF.
\title[Optional Subtitle]{Title}
\author{Albert}{Einstein}

%% Use Roman numerals for the page numbers of the title pages and table of
%% contents.
\frontmatter

\include{title/title}

%% The (optional) dedication can be used to thank someone or display a
%% significant quotation.
\dedication{\epigraph{Science is a wonderful thing \\ if one does not have to earn one's living at it.}{Albert Einstein}}

\tableofcontents

\include{summary/summary}
\include{preface/preface}

%% Use Arabic numerals for the page numbers of the chapters.
\mainmatter

%% Turn on thumb indices.
\thumbtrue

\include{chapter-1/chapter-1}
\include{conclusion/conclusion}
\include{epilogue/epilogue}
\include{acks/acks}

%% Use letters for the chapter numbers of the appendices.
\appendix
%%% Sets the label in the table of contents to "Appendix"
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\let\string\chapappname\string\appendixname}

%%% The appendices have to be included with `\input`, not `\include`
%%% due to a bug in LaTeX, otherwise the appendices will also be
%%% labeled "Chapter"
\input{appendix-a/appendix-a}

%% Turn off thumb indices for unnumbered chapters.
\thumbfalse

\include{cv/cv}
\include{publications/publications}

\end{document}
```

Comment: THANK YOU :) Can you please also help me with how to change the color of "Chapter 1" from black to cyan, so same as the color of the Chapter name.

Comment: And also section name from cyan to black.

Comment: @user127929 I have edited my answer.

Comment: @user127929: If gernot's answer is what you wanted to achieve consider to accept it!