# How can I include the words "chapter" and "appendix" (previously added in the TOC) in the Hyperlinks to the corrensponding chapter / appendix page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, thesis, hyperlink

I am using the same code included in the answer of the question: [How can I add words chapter and appendix in TOC with document class book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358989/how-can-i-add-words-chapter-and-appendix-in-toc-with-document-class-book)

Then, I use the hyperref package and the added words are not included in the hyperlinks of the TOC.

How can I include them in the hyperlinks?

Here is my current output:

[image: Black without hyperlinks and blue denoting the hyperlinks]

where the desired hyperlinks should be applied to the text in black, and the present hyperlinks are denoted in blue.

Comment: Somewhat related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416544/remove-hyperlink-from-table-figure-number-in-lot-lof and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412773/how-can-i-make-the-section-text-in-a-table-of-contents-clickable-but-keep-the-s